# Querying SQL table a second time with info from the first

Tags: sql, peoplesoft

I am running a query against a PeopleSoft database, and am unsure whether it is possible to get information from the same table, based on the initial query, in a single call. For example, the table I am hitting returns EmployeeID, FullName, FirstName, LastName, Position_NBR, and ReportsTo. But the ReportsTo is in the form of the manager's Position_NBR (found in same table), and I would like to get it in the name format. I would like to do something like this, but not sure if it is possible:

```
SELECT Employee_ID, FullName, FirstName, LastName, Position_NBR
,(Select Name From Employee Where Position_NBR='12345') As Manager 
From Employee 
Where EmployeeID='8675309'
```

Is this even possible, or do I need to fully return the first piece before I can use the second?

Comment: That SQL you have is fine, it should work. Are you having a problem with it?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by linking fields.

Here are some examples using the Oracle Database:

e.g.

```sql
SELECT 
  table1.Employee_ID, table1.Name, table1.Boss_ID
  ,(select table2.name from Employee table2 where table1.Boss_ID = table2.Employee_ID) As Manager 
From 
  Employee table1
Where 
  table1.Employee_ID='333'
/
```

Alternately, try a SQL JOIN.

```sql
SELECT 
  table1.Employee_ID, table1.Name, table1.Boss_ID
  ,table2.Name As Manager 
From
  Employee table1
  inner join Employee table2
    on table1.Boss_ID = table2.Employee_ID
Where 
  table1.Employee_ID='333'
/
```

Here is a link to a working example in Oracle 11g with some fake data:

- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/210580/7

[edit]
Starting in [Oracle 12C](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/lateral-inline-views-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-joins-12cr1), an additional join type `LATERAL` is available:

```sql
--Oracle 12 or above
SELECT 
  table1.Employee_ID, table1.Name, table1.Boss_ID
  ,manager.name as manager
From 
  Employee table1
  ,LATERAL
  (
    select table2.name 
    from Employee table2 
    WHERE table1.Boss_ID = table2.Employee_ID
  ) Manager
Where 
  table1.Employee_ID='333'
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can refer to the first table and it's best to limit the result of the subquery to 1 result (just in case the employee has 2 o more managers)

```
SELECT Employee_ID, FullName, FirstName, LastName, Position_NBR
,(Select Top 1 E2.Name From Employee as E2 Where E2.Position_NBR=Employee.Position_NBR) As Manager 
From Employee 
Where EmployeeID='8675309'
```

(T-SQL Syntax)

Comment: That works for a single user (closer). I am trying to get the syntax right for use with multiple users. Today, I pull a list of users from the customer's Service Now ticketing system, and do something like this:

```SELECT
  Employee_ID,
  FullName,
  FirstName,
  LastName,
  Position_NBR,
  ReportsTo,
From
  Employee a Where Employee_ID in ('{0}') -f (($aUsers) -join "','")
```

SQL doesn't like this syntax when I add the sub-query:

Comment: I get the error: 

**Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.**

Am I forced to do a for loop on the queries, and then assemble an array outside the loop?

Comment: Check out the `TOP 1 ` that prevents the error (Subquery returned more than 1 value)